# Finding the appropriate polynomial fit in Python

Tags: regression, python, overfitting, curve-fitting, numpy

Is there a function or library in Python to automatically compute the best polynomial fit for a set of data points?

I am not really interested in the ML use case of generalizing to a set of new data, I am just focusing on the data I have. I realize that the higher the degree, the better the fit. However, I want something that penalizes or looks at where the error elbows. When I say elbowing, I mean something like this (although usually it is not so drastic or obvious): [image]

One idea I had was to use *Numpy's* `polyfit`(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) to compute polynomial regression for a range of orders/degrees. `polyfit` requires the user to specify the degree of polynomial, which poses a challenge because I don't have any assumptions or preconceived notions. The higher the degree of fit, the lower the error will be but eventually it plateaus like the image above. Therefore, if I want to automatically compute the degree of polynomial where the error curve elbows e.g. if my error is E and d is my degree, I want to maximize (E[d+1]-E[d]) - (E[d+1] - E[d]).

Is this even a valid approach? Are there other tools and approaches, perhaps using well-established Python libraries like `numpy` or `scipy`, that can help finding the appropriate polynomial fit (without the order/degree being specified)? I would appreciate any thoughts or suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using polynomials instead of a more stable method, such as splines?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called ["stepwise regression"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepwise_regression). Your predictive variables will be all the powers of your variable  $x$, up to a predetermined term $x^P$. The algorithm will select the subset of those terms that optimize some criteria (normally adjusted $R^2$ or Akaike Information Criteria (AIC)

Some implementations of stepwise regression in Python are:

https://planspace.org/20150423-forward_selection_with_statsmodels/
https://github.com/talhahascelik/python_stepwiseSelection

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would not fit polynomial models to your data willy nilly without good reasons. So assuming this is not a problem and is acceptable to you, I present two options:

1. You use Cross-Validation to determine which model (which polynomial) is the most appropriate, by maximizing a measure such as accuracy or RMSE (depending if you have a classification or regression problem),
2. You use an ANOVA test to compare sequential (nested) models, that is model with polynomial degree 1, degree 2, degree 3, ... and so on; and you use last still significant model which decreases the Sum of Squares (SS).